# How do you convert a scan/jpeg biro sketch into an SVG file without losing detail?

Tags: inkscape, sketch-app

The picture attachment is a SVG file which I uploaded in PNG format.

The detail of the SVG is really good and my vinyl plotter is able to sketch it.

I would like to know how one converts a sketch such as the picture into an SVG file.

[image: SVG file in PNG format]

Comment: related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27892/using-inkscape-to-convert-scanned-color-drawings-to-svg-recommended-or-no

Comment: See also the Inkskape internal [tracing tool](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a graphic program's vector tracing algorithm (this generally requires lots of clean-up afterwards), hand trace/recreate it yourself with vector graphic program of choice (takes time but generally provides the best results), or use a service like http://vectormagic.com/home

Comment: so you basically use the trace as an outline and draw in the detail yourself. I see thanks for your help :)